# Play / SBT / com.typesafe.Config - Excluding the bundled com.typesafe.Config 0.2.1 classes and using the updated 0.4.1 Config

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

I have a an sbt multiproject (sbt 0.11.3) where one of the sub-projects is a PlayProject using play sbt-plugin 2.0.1) and another is my application logic. My application needs to use 0.4.1 version of com.typesafe.Config but I believe the play plugin seems to embed an older version 0.2.1 which causes a conflict when I perform a dist (create a jar) where one of the new methods does not exist in 0.2.1.

I want to know if there is a way I can exclude the old version and only have the new one. I have tired many methods without success (excludes, filtration[If I did that properly at all], etc..)

Thanks in advance to the wizard who either can tell me explicitly how to make this happen, or the chap that tells me it isn't going to happen and why.

Answer:
There was not a good way. The only way was to open the jar remove the config classes in akka and repackage. This was not going to work for us, so I used the older version of the config.